# triple join using sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Let's say we have 3 tables:

table1: firstname, id

table2: id, lastname

table3: lastname, height

and we want to display: firstname, height

I'd likely use full join for that:

```
select firstname, height from
(select firstname, lastname ln from table1 
                               full join table2 on table1.id=table2.id)
full join table3 on ln=table3.lastname
```

but in sqlite, full and right joins do not exist and I need to some how use union to get it.
Any ideas, how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Query:

```
SELECT firstname, height
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
            INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.lastname=table3.lastname
```

Comment: That's the first query I tried but it returns 0 rows.

Comment: @max, then you have no rows that match in all 3 tables.  You can't have a valid query if no rows match.

Answer (score 1):

you need a `JOIN` here between three tables

```
SELECT T1.firstname, T2.lastname, T3.height
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
on T1.id = T2.id
JOIN Table3 T3
on T3.lastname = T2.lastname
```

Comment: This also returns zero rows.

Comment: @max, this means there is no matching data between three tables, you can post data and expected output